# wrong date(one day less) in hibernate from db

Tags: java, hibernate, date

Below is date in DB:

- created_time
- 2018-01-02 04:30:00.756

below is code:

```
List<Date> dataList=new ArrayList<Date>();
query= "SELECT createdTime FROM TableName";
…
…

dataList=selectQuery.list();
for(Object data[] : dataList) {
    System.out.println("Date and time -> "+data[2]); //getting one day less than the original 
}
```

I am getting `01-01-2018` in result if the date is `02-01-2018`.

Comment: Check the default time zones of the database and of your computer.

Comment: do you use hql or native sql query? also can you show how did you map the date in the entity?

Comment: Any particular reason why you are using the long outdated `Date` class? A newer Hibernate can work with `java.time.LocalDate`. If your problem relates to time zone, which it likely does, then this will eliminate it. And java.time is so much nicer to work with. Also, if you’re only interested in the date, not the time of day, use datatype date in your database.

Comment: HI all, thanks for the quick response. I am using native SQL. Date base column is type Date and time zone is UTC. What I observed is for all the time it is showing lesser one day.

Comment: @pramagouni, are you saying that your database column of type `date` (not `datetime`) is holding the value `2018-01-02 04:30:00.756`? That sounds weird to me.

Comment: In any case, thanks for providing more information. When doing so, it’s better to [edit the question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/48238209/edit) and add the information there, so it’s all in one place.

Answer (score 1):

I changed my entity using `LocalDate` from `java.time` instead of using `Date` from `java.util` because I had the same issue in my MySQL docker container.

Trying to solve the problem, I changed the configuration from the MySQL config file but got the same result, and then when looking at the website https://thorben-janssen.com/hibernate-jpa-date-and-time/, I found a table comparing the Java type with the JDBC time.
Based on the table, I changed from `Date` to `LocalDate` and it's working properly now.

Answer (score 0):

the date you got may contain Timezone info, 
so make sure the DB is running the timezone with your code
or better all in UTC